# Showing content of String Arrays

Tags: android

I have this in my `OnItemClick` method.

```
final String[] links = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pokemon_stats);
               String content = links[position];   
               Intent showContent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
               PokedexViewActivity.class);
               showContent.setData(content);
               startActivity(showContent);
```

It doesn't like that I have .setData(content). I believe setData is for URI's. What do I do for a string array? This is the exact error when I hover. `The method setData(Uri) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String)`

I switched it to this and I can't get the pokemon stats:

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
           final String[] links = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pokemon_stats);
           String content = links[position];   
           Intent showContent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
           PokedexViewActivity.class);
           Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
           String pokeStats = extras.getString("MarcsString");
           showContent.putExtra(pokeStats, content);
           startActivity(showContent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `showContent.putExtra("key", value);`

Comment: What would the key and value be?

Comment: Key will be some name that you'll recognize the variable you ship and the value will be the data you want to ship in your case for example

`putExtra("MarcsString", content);`

Comment: This is the right way to pass values between activities. You could also use putStringExtra, but it doesn't really matter for this. In your other activity, you'll get it by using something like this:
`Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String pokeStats = extras.getString("MarcsString");`

Comment: when I clicked on the item I didn't get the stats. I should have got "grass-type" when I clicked.  int position, long id) {
               final String[] links = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pokemon_stats);
               String content = links[position];   
               Intent showContent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
               PokedexViewActivity.class);
               Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
               String pokeStats = extras.getString("MarcsString");
               showContent.putExtra(pokeStats, content);
         startActivity(showContent);

Comment: add this line before you do anything `position = position - listview.getFirstVisibilePosition();` listview can be scrambled sometimes